# AngleAnnotation in Matplotlib: is it implemented?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading this page about: [Scale invariant angle label](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/angle_annotation.html) in Matplotlib

I can follow the example in that page, and reproduce the results. But I wonder if this is already implemented in Matplotlib library itself? or should I create the class myself?

I am using matplotlib `3.4.3` with Python `3.8.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not part of the code-base as of to date.

Looking at the code-base of the version you are using `v3.4.3`, as well as the one of the most recent version as of to date (`v3.5.0b1`), `AngleAnnotation` does not appear.

In the [matplotlib git repository](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) the `AngleAnnotation` class, as sub-class of [`Arc`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html#matplotlib.patches.Arc), occurs only in `examples/text_labels_and_annotations/angle_annotation.py` which is the example you were reading.